# Fastest train from Krakow to Katowice

Tags: poland, krakow

I know there are buses, but I’d really like to do the trip by train if possible.

It’s 4/12/2017 - what is the fastest train?

Comment: There are no "fastest trains" on that route - all are slow. Railway tracks between Kraków and Katowice are in abysmal state so even express trains have to schlepp at 30kph. Buses are faster, cheaper and more frequent. The route isn't particularly scenic either, so there are virtually no benefits of travelling by train.

Comment: **Year 2022 update**: Fortunately not anymore. After 20+ years of waiting (doing nothing) PKP has finally completed track restoration between Krakow and Katowice and travel now [usually takes around 1 hour](http://tiny.cc/x840vz).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three types of trains on this route - REG (regional) and TLK ("Tanie Linie Kolejowe" - "Cheap Railways"), IC (InterCity, much more expensive usually). REG takes 2:13-2:48 hours, TLK 2:45 hours, IC 2:21 hours.

You can find all the connections on [Polish railways website](http://rozklad-pkp.pl/en/tp?queryPageDisplayed=yes&REQ0JourneyStopsS0A=1&REQ0JourneyStopsS0G=5100028&REQ0JourneyStopsS0ID=&REQ0JourneyStops1.0G=&REQ0JourneyStopover1=&REQ0JourneyStops2.0G=&REQ0JourneyStopover2=&REQ0JourneyStopsZ0A=1&REQ0JourneyStopsZ0G=5100020&REQ0JourneyStopsZ0ID=&date=04.12.17&dateStart=04.12.17&dateEnd=04.12.17&REQ0JourneyDate=04.12.17&time=13%3A24&REQ0JourneyTime=13%3A24&REQ0HafasSearchForw=1&existBikeEverywhere=yes&existHafasAttrInc=yes&existHafasAttrInc=yes&REQ0JourneyProduct_prod_section_0_0=1&REQ0JourneyProduct_prod_section_1_0=1&REQ0JourneyProduct_prod_section_2_0=1&REQ0JourneyProduct_prod_section_3_0=1&REQ0JourneyProduct_prod_section_0_1=1&REQ0JourneyProduct_prod_section_1_1=1&REQ0JourneyProduct_prod_section_2_1=1&REQ0JourneyProduct_prod_section_3_1=1&REQ0JourneyProduct_prod_section_0_2=1&REQ0JourneyProduct_prod_section_1_2=1&REQ0JourneyProduct_prod_section_2_2=1&REQ0JourneyProduct_prod_section_3_2=1&REQ0JourneyProduct_prod_section_0_3=1&REQ0JourneyProduct_prod_section_1_3=1&REQ0JourneyProduct_prod_section_2_3=1&REQ0JourneyProduct_prod_section_3_3=1&REQ0JourneyProduct_opt_section_0_list=0%3A000000&existOptimizePrice=1&existHafasAttrExc=yes&REQ0HafasChangeTime=0%3A1&existSkipLongChanges=0&REQ0HafasAttrExc=&REQ0HafasAttrExc=&REQ0HafasAttrExc=&REQ0HafasAttrExc=&REQ0HafasAttrExc=&REQ0HafasAttrExc=&REQ0HafasAttrExc=&REQ0HafasAttrExc=&REQ0HafasAttrExc=&REQ0HafasAttrExc=&REQ0HafasAttrExc=&REQ0HafasAttrExc=&existHafasAttrInc=yes&existHafasAttrExc=yes&wDayExt0=Pn%7CWt%7C%C5%9Ar%7CCz%7CPt%7CSo%7CNd&start=start&existUnsharpSearch=yes&came_from_form=1#focus), on this particular day REG leaves at 03:12,  07:58, 16:30 and 20:26, the one at 16:30 being the fastest one (2:13 hours).

Comment: **Year 2022 update**: Fortunately not anymore. After 20+ years of waiting (doing nothing) PKP has finally completed track restoration between Krakow and Katowice and travel now [usually takes around 1 hour](http://tiny.cc/x840vz).